# Eanbling/Disabling preprocessor for VS C++ code compilation from command line

Tags: visual-studio, qt, jenkins

We are trying to compile our Qt + C++ code from command prompt using VS.

- Qt version: 5.15.2 - msvc20129 compiler
- VS: 2019 v16.8.4
- OS: Windows 10

We are creating 2 versions of binary. One is to provide to the customer. And the second version is to generate a build for test automation team. To generate build for test automation team, we need to enable few additional lines in the source code, for which we are using some preprocessors. And the same needs to be disabled for customer build. To avoid code changes to enable and disable the preprocessor, we thought of doing it from the command prompt. And with some search on Google we learned about the CL option. Following are the steps we are following:

1. The code compilation is getting triggered from Jenkin's server. We are reading a check box state to enable or disable TA build from buld configuratoin page.
2. By default the preprocessor are disabled (not defined). So additional code for test automation, will be commented.
3. So if the checkbox in the build configuration page (of jenkin's server) is checked then we are passing a string "true" while executing the batch file. As follows:

   ```
   call path/code_build.bat true
   ```
4. If the 1st argument received by the batch file is "true", we care calling the CL command to enable the preprocessor. As follows:

   ```
   set CL=/DENABLE_TEST_AUTOMATION_FLAG
   ```

By putting echo statements, we can see that the first argument we are receiving is "true". And accordingly we are setting the test automation flag as follows.

```
echo --------------------------------- Build - Release -----------------------------------
echo command line argument %1
if "%1%"=="true" (
echo --------------------------------- ENABLE_TEST_AUTOMATION_FLAG enabled ------------------------
set CL=/DENABLE_TEST_AUTOMATION_FLAG
) else (
echo --------------------------------- ENABLE_TEST_AUTOMATION_FLAG disabled -----------------------
)
```

But the section of code which required for the TA build is not getting enabled.

And also if there is any better way of doing the same (enabling preprocessor from command line, while compiling the code from command prompt)

Comment: I think `set CL=/DENABLE_TEST_AUTOMATION_FLAG` sets rather an environment variable than a preprocessor define. You should set it along with the compiler options.

Comment: @vahancho thanks for your reply. We tested this locally. Using this we are able to enable/disable preprocessor for sample code. But not able to achieve the same, when doing it from the Jenkins. Is ther any other way to this?

Comment: @BikashRDas `if "%1%"=="true"` That has an extra `%` at the end, and also doubles the `"` quotes. Try `if "%~1"=="true"` instead.

Comment: @dxiv As I said, I am able to correctly identify the input to batch file and calling the "set CL=/DENABLE_TEST_AUTOMATION_FLAG" correctly. But this is not working as per our expectation. I tried this with sample application locally on my PC. It is working fine

Comment: @BikashRDas It can't work locally, either. If you run `call code_build.bat "true"` then the conditional expands to `if ""true"" == "true" (...)` which causes the `else` to be executed. It will work if you run  `call code_build.bat true` instead, but that's different from what you wrote.